# Python .CSV Leaderboard Write - Score Randomly Doesn't Save

Tags: python, csv, pygame, leaderboard

Hi I am having a strange problem with my leaderboard in Python. I have the player score variable being written to the file, this usually works however sometimes it just writes 0 instead of the number they scored. This only happens occasionally but it needs fixed. I think it has something to do with the delay used before setting playerscore = 0 but I am not sure what to change to fix it. Code below.

```
 with open('Leaderboard.csv', 'a', newline='') as filepath:

                        a = csv.writer(filepath, delimiter=',')

                        data = [[PlayerScore, player_name]]

                        a.writerows(data)

                f = open('Leaderboard.csv')

                csv_f = csv.reader(f)
                name = []
                for row in csv_f:
                        name.append(row)

                f.close()
                print(PlayerScore)
                # set PlayerScore to 0
                pygame.time.delay(100)
                PlayerScore = 0
```

Comment: lets begin by formatting your code

Comment: Make sure your code is [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can run and analyze it without changing it first.

Comment: It seems it's not possible to reproduce the error, so post a complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv


PlayerScore = 25
player_name = 'Fry'

# Append to the csv.
with open('Leaderboard.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow((PlayerScore, player_name))

# Read the csv.
with open('Leaderboard.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    score_list = list(csv.reader(file))
    for row in score_list:
        print(row)

# Afterwards reset the score and name if you have to.
PlayerScore = 0
player_name = ''
```

Don't forget to convert the scores from strings to ints (or floats) if you want to sort them correctly, otherwise they would get sorted lexicographically.